# check if current user has favorited the tweet or not

Tags: iphone, twitter, ios7

I need to check whether current user has favourited the tweet or not?!!

I am using `twitter api 1.1` and I am confused as which attribute to use from the following attributes from the twitter api response ***json***

**favorite_count**

**favourites_count**

**favorited**

Answer (score 2):

The favorite attribute for tweets returned from the search API will always return false. This is a "perspectival" attribute which is not supported by the search API. According to [this thread in the twitter community](https://twittercommunity.com/t/favorited-reports-as-false-even-if-status-is-already-favorited-by-the-user/11145/2), there are no plans to change this any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the tweets from authenticated user say A, the response you will get from the twitter api contains parameter `favorited` which contains `BOOL` value.

```
TRUE signifies user A favorited the tweet
FALSE signifies user A not favorited the tweet
```

Sample tweet response in [JSON format](https://gist.github.com/hrp/900964).

Comment: I need to check for favorite status from the tweets which I am getting from the "search" api. for example I am getting 100 tweets each time when I call following api :

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json

now I need to test whether any tweets from these 100 tweet is my favorited or not?

Comment: YEs, each tweet contains 'favorited' parameter which will tell you whether the tweet is favorited by the user you are using to get the search results or not.

Comment: @VinayJain no its not working every time I am getting favorited = 0 Any luck for you ?

Comment: @Maulik it was working for me that time but not checked recently.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow Twitter Developer Site on the following link to get your most recent favorited tweets.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/favorites/list